# Error building react native project with the package "opentok-react-native"

Tags: android, react-native, opentok

I'm trying to build a React Native project which uses **opentok-react-native version 0.12.2**. When running my android build it fails with the following error complaining that the android support annotation package does not exist. Has anyone experienced this before?

```
Task :opentok-react-native:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

Comment: Did you solve that problem?